# get mnist data as input for my program (RBMs)

Tags: c++, matlab, mnist

i need to go from binary data when testing my RBM to simple images as MNIST. but just wonder how i could pass them as input to my program. from matlab side. Replacing X with mnist data.

```
 X=  [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0; ...
  1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0; ...
  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0; ...
  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0; ...
  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0; ...
  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0];

X = int32(X);
```

above is how i actually pass them (also they are binaries)
and here is how i run them:

```
 rbm = RBM(X,hidden_E,training_epochs,k, learning_rate)
```

so wondering how i could manage to replace my X matrix with mnist data set instead?

Comment: I have no idea what the inputs of RBM are shaped like.  What are they supposed to be shaped like? What are the expected sizes?

Comment: for a start i have been using binary number : as shown above my X is the matrix containing the training input fed to the RBM sofar. and the main goal in future is to train the machine for image recognition. I don't if that helps understanding what my problem is? thanks